# undefined method 'projects_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Tearing my hair out here. I have a brand model, this has_many projects and the projects belong_to the brand. I'm trying to create projects inside the brand but I'm running into the following error:

```
undefined method `projects_path'
```

Everything seems to be in order. Some of my code can be found below:

**Routes**

```
resources :brands do
    resources :projects do
      resources :ideas
    end
  end
```

**Brands**

```
<%= link_to 'Create New Project', new_brand_project_path(@brand) %>
```

The routing is working, as the link I'm sent to is brand/brand_id/projects/new - but this is where I get the error I mentioned earlier.

**Update - The original problem was fixed, now when I save the project I'm getting the same error, but this time something is wrong with 'create'...**

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /projects
  # GET /projects.json
  def index
    @projects = Project.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @projects }
    end
  end

  # GET /projects/1
  # GET /projects/1.json
  def show
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @project }
    end
  end

  # GET /projects/new
  # GET /projects/new.json
  def new
    @brand = Brand.find(params[:brand_id])
    @project = Project.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @project }
    end
  end

  # GET /projects/1/edit
  def edit
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /projects
  # POST /projects.json
  def create
    @project = Project.new(params[:project])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.save
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @project, status: :created, location: @project }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: you don't have any `projects_path` helper with these routes, but you have `brand_projects_path(brand_id: brand.id)` (all projects belonging to this brand), should lead you to the ProjectsController#index

Comment: That error shouldn't be coming from `new_brand_project_path(@brand)` because your resources declaration is correct.  It's possible that it's coming from the controller where you have redirect helper call or in your view where you have another `link_to projects_path...`

Comment: Nope, just to be sure I did a find all on "projects_path" and removed all traces. Still getting the error. The error also points towards my projects controller (new). Any ideas?

Comment: @ItsJoeTurner: can you paste your log with detailed error message.

Comment: @AmanGarg - `app/views/projects/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_projects__form_html_erb__4524375367829344447_70287520073440'
app/views/projects/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_projects_new_html_erb___307675857345156484_70287520242580'
app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:29:in `new'`

Comment: Could you show `views/projects/new.html.erb`

Comment: I have fixed this by adding "@brand = Brand.find(params[:brand_id])" to the projects controller but I'm now getting the same error for *create*, again in the project controller.

Comment: Post your project controller code please.

Comment: Thanks so far guys... I'm now updating the question with my controller code. @GraemeMcLean

Answer (score 0):

Add `@brand = Brand.find(params[:brand_id])` to all your methods.

Remember the view comes back to the controller each time and can't remember what was set last time.  The `new` method builds you the html form, but the `create` method is used to take the data and create the new record.  But the `create` method doesn't know what you did in `new`, it can only work from the parameter data it was given.

Comment: Thanks for this, but the error I'm now getting is ` undefined method `project_url' ` and it's pointing me towards the *create* method in my project controller. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm afraid that's not done the job - The error I see after creating, but not saving a project is: undefined method `project_url'

Comment: Change your redirect: instead of `redirect_to @project` try `redirect_to brand_project_path(@brand, @project)`